# pyspark: Save schemaRDD as json file

Tags: python, json, apache-spark

I am looking for a way to export data from Apache Spark to various other tools in JSON format. I presume there must be a really straightforward way to do it.

Example: I have the following JSON file 'jfile.json':

```
{"key":value_a1, "key2":value_b1},
{"key":value_a2, "key2":value_b2},
{...}
```

where each line of the file is a JSON object. These kind of files can be easily read into PySpark with

```
jsonRDD = jsonFile('jfile.json')
```

and then look like (by calling jsonRDD.collect()):

```
[Row(key=value_a1, key2=value_b1),Row(key=value_a2, key2=value_b2)]
```

Now I want to save these kind of files back to a pure JSON file.

I found this entry on the Spark User list:

http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Updating-exising-JSON-files-td12211.html

that claimed using

```
RDD.saveAsTextFile(jsonRDD)
```

After doing this, the text file looks like

```
Row(key=value_a1, key2=value_b1)
Row(key=value_a2, key2=value_b2)
```

, i.e., the jsonRDD has just been plainly written to the file. I would have expected a kind of an "automagic" conversion back to JSON format after reading the Spark User List entry. My goal is to have a file that looks like 'jfile.json' mentioned in the beginning.

Am I missing a really obvious easy way to do this?

I read http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html, searched google, the user list and stack overflow for answers, but almost all answers deal with reading and parsing JSON into Spark. I even bought the book 'Learning Spark', but the examples there (p. 71) just lead to the same output file as above.

Can anybody help me out here? I feel like I am missing just a small link in here

Cheers and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see an easy way to do it. One solution is to convert each element of the `SchemaRDD` to a `String`, ending up with an `RDD[String]` where each of the elements is formatted JSON for that row. So, you need to write your own JSON serializer. That's the easy part. It may not be super fast but it should work in parallel, and you already know how to save an `RDD` to a text file.

The key insight is that you can get a representation of the schema out of the `SchemaRDD` by calling the `schema` method. Then each `Row` handed to you by map needs to be traversed recursively *in conjunction with* the schema. This is actually an in-tandem list traversal for flat JSON, but you may also need to consider nested JSON.

The rest is just a small matter of Python, which I don't speak, but I do have this [working in Scala](https://github.com/spirom/LearningSpark/blob/master/src/main/scala/sql/OutputJSON.scala) in case it helps you. The parts where the Scala code gets dense actually don't depend on deep Spark knowledge so if you can understand the basic recursion and know Python you should be able to make it work. The bulk of the work for you is figuring out how to work with a `pyspark.sql.Row` and a `pyspark.sql.StructType` in the Python API.

One word of caution: I'm pretty sure my code doesn't yet work in the case of missing values -- the `formatItem` method needs to handle null elements.

**Edit:** In **Spark 1.2.0** the `toJSON` method was introduced to `SchemaRDD`, making this a *much* simpler problem -- see the answer by @jegordon.

Comment: An introduction to JSON support in Spark SQL
https://databricks.com/blog/2015/02/02/an-introduction-to-json-support-in-spark-sql.html

Answer (score 5):

You can use the method toJson() , it allows you to convert a SchemaRDD into a MappedRDD of JSON documents.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=tojson#pyspark.sql.SchemaRDD.toJSON

Comment: This worked well and is a one liner: `res.toJSON().saveAsTextFile('/tmp/out/')`

Answer (score 1):

I have been using `org.apache.spark.sql.json` in Spark SQL directly from the SQL console. Not the most efficient way, and it might be considered a hack, but it gets the job done.

```
CREATE TABLE jsonTable (
    key STRING,
    value STRING
)
USING org.apache.spark.sql.json
OPTIONS (
    PATH "destination/path"
);
```

Once the table is created, insert the data from a registered temp table or any other table

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE jsonTable
SELECT * FROM tempTable;
```

**NOTE**: Seems that this is launching a hive map reduce job creating multiple file parts under the provided path. Slow execution to be expected

**NOTE**: the path provided during the table creation is on hdfs, not the local file system.

**NOTE**: I haven't tried embedding this into a script using SQLContext.sql but it might be feasible

**NOTE**: selecting from the table jsonTable might fail due to the serialization