# Is loading and querying of structured data other than HBASE possible in Apache Spark GraphX?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

So I managed to load 2 XML files, representing Vertex and Edge data, into Hadoop/HDFS using Pig XMLloader and created Hive tables from it.

I want to use this Vertex and Edge data to create a Spark GraphX based Graph Database. I understood from the Spark GraphX documentation that in addition to flat files sources HBASE tables can be used to source Spark GraphX. I couldn't find any Spark GraphX documentation regarding using other structured big data sources such as Hive.

However, in SparkSQL Hive is supported as a source of structured data.
JSON structured data is also supported within SparkSQL.

Does the support of Hive in SparkSQL also means that Hive using HiveContext is supported natively in Spark GraphX? 
What about the usage of JSON source files to create VertexRDDs using .jsonFile(name.json)as a source?

Comment: Surely you mean GraphX rather than SparkX ?

Comment: Thanks.. It was already late when I wrote the question.. I will edit the question. Do you have an answer? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Spiro. SchemaRDD is indeed the way to go.

I upgraded Apache Spark to version 1.2 using the HortonWorks distribution.
In this distribution Hive tables are supported in a Spark hiveContext using SchemaRDDs accessing tables in HCatalog.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can see is to create one or more `SchemaRDD`s using one of the approaches you describe, and then take advantage of the fact that `SchemaRDD` extends `RDD[Row]`.  Then you can use the usual Spark and GraphX approaches to convert it to whatever you want.

Alas, `Row` has some disadvantages. It's marked as a "developer API", and is documented about as well as that would lead you to expect. It also isn't the friendliest thing to use, as you can't look fields up by name, but have to do it positionally -- basically it just extends `Seq[Any]`. You can either guess the position of your fields according to the query you used to extract them, or you can get a representation of the schema (a `Seq[StructField]`) out of the `SchemaRDD` by calling the `schema` method. You find the field you want in the schema, and it'll be in the corresponding position in the row!

In case it helps you can see me [using this approach](https://github.com/spirom/LearningSpark/blob/master/src/main/scala/sql/OutputJSON.scala) in some code I wrote while answering a [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26737251/pyspark-save-schemardd-as-json-file) here. I'm not actually going so far as *recommending* that you make this much use of developer APIs, and you'll be skating on thin ice, but it's probably what you need to do.